# How to get Experience Fragment component data as json in page level

Tags: fragment, aem, experience-manager

I've a page with multiple components and all the components have @Exporter annotation and data is exporting as json, but header and footer components are added as Experience Fragment, when hitting model.json for this page I'm unable to export/ see XF ( Header & Footer ) component data, could someone help me how to get XF component data at page level please..

I Expecting XF component data to be exported as a json in page level

Comment: Did you find a way to do it? A straightforward but limited way is to request /content/experience-fragment/path/to/xf.json or content/experience-fragment/path/to/xf.1.json but it is not optimal. Also see https://github.com/adobe/aem-core-wcm-components/pull/1117